# Returning an instance of the concrete child class from a method in the abstract parent class

Tags: java, generics, abstract-class, abstraction

I'm wondering if there's a better way to do this. What I want is to have a concrete method in an abstract class return the concrete instance that extends the abstract class.

Here's what I'm doing now:

```
abstract class ParentClass<T extends ParentClass> extends RelativeLayout {
    ...
    public T aMethod(){
        return (T)this;
    }
}
```

and

```
class ChildClass1 extends ParentClass<ChildClass1>{
...
}
```

I don't think I should have to cast this to T since this always is an instance of T.

Comment: This will break if I decide to do this: `class ChildClass2 extends ParentClass<ChildClass1>`.

Now, I'm not entirely clear on what you want to achieve or why you want to achieve it.  If you want to update your question accordingly I might be able to provide an answer.

Comment: @JoeC What I have works, but it is requiring me to cast 'this' in the parent class to T. It should already know that 'this' is an instance of T, so I was wondering if there was a more elegant solution that just wasn't smart enough to think of. Either one that didn't require me to cast or one that returned the child instance without the use of generics at all.

Comment: Try what you have with the subclass I suggested and let me know if it still works.

Comment: "It should already know that 'this' is an instance of T" But it's not in the case JoeC mentions.

Comment: "It should already know that 'this' is an instance of T" no. Only description for `T` is that `<T extends ParentClass>`, but that doesn't prevent `ParentClass` from setting other `T` than its own type. Take a look at example from @JoeC comment. You can have `class ChildClass2 extends ParentClass<ChildClass1>` so there `T` is set to be `ChildClass1` while `this` will be instance of `ChildClass2`.

Comment: Suppose I made the class signature into:

`abstract class ParentClass<T extends ParentClass<T>> extends RelativeLayout {`

Wouldn't that guarantee that `this` is an instance of `T`?

Comment: There's no clean way to do this in Java. If you want to avoid the cast, you can make `aMethod` abstract and override it in the subclass to return `this`.

Comment: @shmosel That's what I'm figuring. Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: @der_Fidelis No, because `this` might be an instance of `ChildClass2 extends ParentClass<ChildClass1>`, like @JoeC said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that there is no way to reference the type of "this very class". This is why you have to use constructs like `abstract class Base<T extends Base<T>>`. But as many mentioned in comments, nothing prohibits you from defining `Subclass1 extends <Subclass2>`. There is just now syntactic way to guarantee that `T` is "this very class".

You can, however, enforce this guarantee in the runtime. You can use something like [TypeTools](https://github.com/jhalterman/typetools) or other methods to extract used generic type and the make sure that current instance has this type. This would probably result in something like:

```
public abstract class Base<T extends Base<T>> {

    protected Base() {
        final Class<?> t = (Class<?>) ((ParameterizedType) getClass().getGenericSuperclass())
                .getActualTypeArguments()[0];
        if (!t.isInstance(this)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
    }

    public T getInstance() {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        T thisIsT = (T) this;
        return thisIsT;
    }
}
```

This class can be instantiated:

```
public class Extension1 extends Base<Extension1> {}
```

But this one not:

```
public class Extension2 extends Base<Extension1> {}
```

The `Base` constructor guarantees that `this` is instance of `T` therefore the cast of `this` to `T` is safe.